# React-Native/Redux dispatch firing multiple times in action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I'm making a React/Redux app. In one of my actions, `dispatch` is firing 6-8 times when called for no apparent reason. See `addMarkersRequestAddress` below in the action file for my component:

```
export function addMarkersSuccess(response) {
  return {
    type: 'addMarkersSuccess',
    status: 'success',
    response: response,
    receivedAt: Date.now(),
  };
}

export function addMarkersFailure(error) {
  return {
    type: 'addMarkersFailure',
    status: 'error',
    error: error,
    receivedAt: Date.now(),
  };
}

export function addMarkersRequestCoordinates(submitFormData) {


  // Why is this always returning addMarkersFailure? Is it possibly related to why it always fires multiple times?
  // Same code as in virtualFenceWalk actions
  return (dispatch) => {

    console.log('running addMarkersRequestCoordinates');
    console.log('submitFormData: ',submitFormData);

    let JSONbody = JSON.stringify(submitFormData);
    console.log('JSONbody: ',JSONbody);

    fetch('http://localhost:8080/virtualFence', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSONbody
        }).then(function(response){
          dispatch(addMarkersSuccess(response));
        }).catch(function(error) {
          dispatch(addMarkersFailure(error));
        });

  }
}

export function addMarkersRequestAddress(submitFormData) {
  return (dispatch) => {

    console.log('running addMarkersRequestAddress');
    console.log('submitFormData: ',submitFormData);

    let JSONbody = JSON.stringify(submitFormData);
    console.log('JSONbody: ',JSONbody);

    // Make a request to a backend route that gets the coordinates from the Google Maps API
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/virtualFenceAddress', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSONbody
        }).then(function(response){
          console.log('addMarkersRequestAddress success');
          console.log('response: ',response);
          dispatch(addMarkersSuccess(response));
        }).catch(function(error) {
          console.log('addMarkersRequestAddress failure');
          console.log('error: ',error);
          dispatch(addMarkersFailure(error));
        });

  }

}
```

When this code runs, `addMarkersSuccess` will fire 6-8 times. It is somehow related to `dispatch` specifically, because if I remove the `dispatch` calls and leave only the console logs, `addMarkersSuccess` fires once as expected and that's it. It also seems unrelated to `fetch` or asynchronicity since an identical outcome occurs if `fetch` is removed and the same thing is tried in the main body of the function.

Here is the container wrapping around the component (since I've narrowed it down to an issue with how `dispatch` is called, as without `dispatch` other parts of the action only fire once, maybe there is an issue with how `dispatch` is set up here?):

```
import React, { Component }                                             from 'react';
import PropTypes                                                        from 'prop-types';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, TouchableOpacity, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';
import { bindActionCreators }                                           from 'redux';
import { connect }                                                      from 'react-redux';
import VirtualFence                                                     from '../components/VirtualFence';
import * as VirtualFenceActions                                         from '../actions/virtualFence';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  back: {
    margin: 10,
    fontSize: 20,
  },
});

// Map the Redux state to props
@connect(
  state => ({
    bigState: state,
    markers: state.markers,
  }),
  dispatch => bindActionCreators(VirtualFenceActions, dispatch),
)

export default class VirtualFenceContainer extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <VirtualFence {...this.props} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is where the action is called in the component itself:

```
render() {

    const {
      addMarkersRequestAddress, addMarkersSuccess, addMarkersFailure
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.toggleModal}>
          <Text style={styles.bottomText}>Add markers by street address</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Modal isVisible={this.state.isVisible}>
          <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.toggleModal}>
              <Text style={styles.bottomText}>Hide me!</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <Form
              ref="form"
              type={Points}
              options={pointsOptions}
            />
            <Button title="Add form field" onPress={this.addFormField}></Button>
            <Button title="Delete form field" onPress={this.deleteFormField}></Button>
            <Button
              title="Submit markers"
              onPress={(argument)=>addMarkersRequestAddress(this.refs.form.getValue())}
            />
          </View>
        </Modal>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

While not answering my question, some other answers here and elsewhere seemed to hint that the resolution may have something to do with my `configureStore.js` file, so here it is:

```
/* eslint global-require: 0 */

import { Platform } from 'react-native';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import reducer from './reducers';

// Presumably I need to add the other action files here somehow? Nothing seems to change as long as one file is listed...
import * as actionCreators from './actions/activityTracker';

let composeEnhancers = compose;
if (__DEV__) {
  // Use it if Remote debugging with RNDebugger, otherwise use remote-redux-devtools
  /* eslint-disable no-underscore-dangle */
  composeEnhancers = (window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ ||
    require('remote-redux-devtools').composeWithDevTools)({
    name: Platform.OS,
    ...require('../package.json').remotedev,
    actionCreators,
  });
  /* eslint-enable no-underscore-dangle */
}

const enhancer = composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk));

// I think the problem with multiple dispatches may be in here
// See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49734848/redux-dispatch-fires-multiple-times
export default function configureStore(initialState) {
  const store = createStore(reducer, initialState, enhancer);
  if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept(() => {
      store.replaceReducer(require('./reducers').default);
    });
  }
  return store;
}
```

Please note that I don't really know what this file is doing. I began the app using [react-native-boilerplate](https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-boilerplate) so this file is taken from there. If changes need to be made there, it would be super appreciated if you can detail what exactly those changes do.

EDIT 1: When this post was originally written, all dispatches after the first threw errors. After some further work in other parts of the application, the additional firings all log successful now. However, the essential question (the cause of the multiple firings) remains.

EDIT 2: Added the container wrapping around the component.

Comment: Can you show how you use these actions in your component? Please show a [mcve]. Note the word "complete".

Comment: I've added the render function from the component where this action is called.

Comment: Please read the link I gave in my previous comment.

Comment: Where are you executing the **addMarkersRequestCoordinates** function? Your reducer action seems ok.

Comment: I did read the link. What is the issue?

Comment: `addMarkersRequestCoordinates` is used in the same context in another component (and has the same multiple-dispatch problem). It's only included here as it's part of the file and I wanted to give the entire context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause of my problem turned out to be in the file where I call the [combineReducers](https://redux.js.org/api-reference/combinereducers) helper function. I did not suspect this file had anything to do with the problem, so I had not posted it. For components with multiple keys in the initial state object, I incorrectly thought I had to do an import for each key, when in fact I needed a single import for each reducer file. I imported six variables from the `virtualFence` reducer, and each one caused `dispatch` to fire.

This is the incorrect version:

```
import { combineReducers }       from 'redux';
import nav                       from './nav';
import virtualFence              from './virtualFence';
import latitude                  from './virtualFence';
import longitude                 from './virtualFence';
import latitudeDelta             from './virtualFence';
import longitudeDelta            from './virtualFence';
import markers                   from './virtualFence';

export default combineReducers({
  nav,
  latitude,
  longitude,
  latitudeDelta,
  longitudeDelta,
  markers,
  virtualFence,
});
```

And this is the correct version:

```
import { combineReducers }           from 'redux';
import nav                           from './nav';
import virtualFence                  from './virtualFence';

export default combineReducers({
  nav,
  virtualFence,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

are you using preventDefault() when calling event this might be the case:

```
function ActionLink() {
  function handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('The link was clicked.');
  }

  return (
    <a href="#" onClick={handleClick}>
      Click me
    </a>
  );
}
```

use preventdefault to disallow to call method when page is loading

```
<Button title="Add form field" onPress={this.addFormField}></Button>
            <Button title="Delete form field" onPress={this.deleteFormField}></Button>
            <Button
              title="Submit markers"
              onPress={(argument)=>addMarkersRequestAddress(this.refs.form.getValue())}
            />
```

Comment: This doesn't fix it. I created a wrapper function called `onPress` with `e.preventDefault()` that then called `addMarkersRequestAddress`, but multiple dispatches remained.

Answer (score 0):

So you state:

> `addMarkersSuccess` will fire once, followed by several firings of `addMarkersFailure`

`addMarkersFailure` only gets called when there is an error. This error, of course, contains all the information you need to solve the problem. In particular, it has a stack that indicates not only the exact place the error was fired, but a complete call stack that indicates the entire call chain leading up to the error.

When a `Promise` has several stages, each stage has an opportunity to fail. A catch following any of the stages will be passed the error.

So:

```
Promise.resolve('This is just a string, and no error')
  .then(theString => {
    throw new Error('This is not the original promise result, but a new one: A rejection.');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('Something went wrong. Maybe it happened in the original promise.');
    console.log('Maybe it happened later. To find out, look closely at this:');
    console.log(err.stack);
  });
```

In your case, it's probably `dispatch` that throws. Now, there's nothing wrong with `dispatch` itself, but when it goes to call *your* reducer, the reducer is probably doing something wrong and throwing an error. This in turn leads your `.catch` callback (aka the rejection handler) to be called.

Since you did not include your reducer code I can't point out the error in it. However, you should be able to find it by examining the error message and stack.

Comment: I didn't include reducer code because the error occurs even if the entire content of the reducer is simply `return state`. As such, I feel I've reliably identified that the reducer itself is not the problem. Regardless, this doesn't really address why the dispatch call actually works the first time.

Comment: Have you inspected the error? What is the error message?

Comment: Just tried it again this morning--and instead of getting an error, I get a successful dispatch 6 times. I've done some further work on the code since originally posting this. This additional work mostly relates to incorporating Immutable.js throughout the entire flow of the application, so that may have somehow solved what caused the failures. But the multiple dispatch problem remains, and that is what needs to get solved.

Answer (score -1):

In your `addMarkersRequestAddress` action, try to return the `dispatch` in `.then()` like:

```
.then((response) => {
      dispatch(addMarkersSuccess(response));
    }).catch((error) => {
      dispatch(addMarkersFailure(error));
    });
```

Maybe this will work.

Comment: I do return the `dispatch` in `then()` already. Is your point to use fat arrow functions?

Comment: My point is somehow return the `dispatch` because it seems the function are not returning.

Comment: Your code does not differ from mine in any way except for the use of a fat arrow function.

Comment: I think you should return the response to your function: try this `return fetch('http://localhost:8080/virtualFenceAddress', ...`

Comment: The same behavior remains when using `return`.